# Optimal growth of an oscillating integral

Tags: integration, asymptotics

Let $f\in H^1(\mathbb{R}^3)$, with $f\equiv0$ inside a ball around the origin. For $t>0$, consider the following integral
$$I(t):=\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}e^{i|x|^2/t}\frac{f(x)}{|x|}dx$$

It`s easy to show that $I(t)$ is finite for every $t>0$. Indeed an integration by parts gives:
$$I(t)=-\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}e^{i|x|^2/t}\vec{x}\cdot\nabla\left(\frac{f(x)}{|x|(3+2i|x|^2/t)}\right)dx$$
Expanding the gradient and applying Cauchy-Schwarz we get
$$|I(t)|\lesssim t\Vert f\Vert_{H^1(\mathbb{R}^3)}$$
In particular $|I(t)|$ grows at most linearly as $t\rightarrow +\infty$.

Nevertheless, i think we don't need a full derivative of the oscillating factor to get the convergence of the integral, and consequently the growth in $t$ should be actually slower.

Hence my question is: **what is the optimal growth as $t\rightarrow +\infty$** ?

This question is inspired by the answer of Fan Zheng in [Convergence of an oscillatory integral](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/222568/convergence-of-an-oscillatory-integral) .

Comment: I'm afraid you missed an $|x|$ in the denominator of the integrand; otherwise I fail to see why $\nabla f/|x|$ is integrable using Cauchy-Schwarz.

Comment: Isn't $|I(t)| \leq \|f \|_2 (\int_{|x| \geq \varepsilon} |x|^{-2} dx)^{1/2}$, where $\varepsilon > 0$ is chosen so that $f(x) = 0$ for $|x| \leq \varepsilon$?

Comment: @MattYoung: $1/|x|^2$ isn't integrable in $d\ge 2$.

Comment: @ChristianRemling: Thanks, I was thinking about $d=1$.

Comment: I don't really want to type up an answer, but I seem to get $O(t^{1/2})$ by using the trivial bound for $|x| \leq U$ (with $U$ chosen later, $U \geq t^{1/2}$), and integrating by parts for $|x| \geq U$.  The choice $U=t$ seems to be best.